# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in For loop (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I'm having a weird problem with part of my code and a 'for' loop. Here's the snippet of code that is strange:

```
var length_value = entry_array.length;

console.log(length_value);

for(var k = 0; k <= length_value; k++){
    j = k + 1;
    $.each(entry_array[k], function(key, value){
        post_data = post_data + key + j + '=' + value + '&';
    }); 
}
```

When I run the code it logs `3` to the console (which is the number of elements in the `entry_array` array variable. When it goes to run the `for` loop, it gives me a `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I've run the for loop successfully by swapping out `length_value` for `3` and it works. I've tried this:

```
length_value = entry_array.length; //Thinking it had something to do with 'scope'
```

And this:

```
var length_value = parseInt(entry_array.length) //Thinking it had something to do with the variable type
```

And neither worked. So the for loop syntax is correct and `entry_array.length` has a value but it doesn't work together. What's going on here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: 0-based arrays should be indexed from 0 to `< length`, not `<= length`

Comment: Do you have a StackTrace? I assume that the error comes from $.each()?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, that seems to be the trick but I can't figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0-based arrays should be indexed from 0 to `< length`, not `<= length`

```
var length_value = entry_array.length;

console.log(length_value);

for(var k = 0; k < length_value; k++){
    j = k + 1;
    $.each(entry_array[k], function(key, value){
        post_data = post_data + key + j + '=' + value + '&';
    }); 
}
```

e.g. If you have 3 elements, you want indexes of 0, 1 & 2. `<=` will give 0, 1, 2 & 3

*If there are further issues, you need to show a sample of the array content*

Comment: Ah, totally makes sense. Thanks! (I'll accept the answer when it allows me.)